# How can I assign default values to all undefined properties of an object being passed as a function parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, arguments, destructuring

I have a function which takes in an object as an argument. The object's property defaults are decided. I want the given argument's missing entries to be assigned the corresponding default values. However as of now my function argument only returns the entry it was given in the function call.

**My Attempts**

```js
function x(obj1 = {foo: 'bar', fizz: 'buzz'}) {
  console.log(obj1);
}

x({foo: 10}); // {foo: 10}


function y(obj2 = ({foo: 'bar'}, {fizz: 'buzz'})) {
  console.log(obj2);
}

y({foo: 20}); // {foo: 20}


function z(obj3 = ({foo: foo} = {foo: 'bar'}, {fizz: fizz} = {fizz: 'buzz'})) {
  console.log(obj3)
}


z({foo: 30}); // {foo: 30}
```

**My Goal**

```js
function f(/* <{foo: 'bar', fizz: 'buzz'}> */) {
   console.log(/* <obj> */);
}

f({foo: 40}); // {foo: 40, fizz: 'buzz'}
```

Comment: Simply [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) the passed object to your default object. `function f(obj) {obj = Object.assign({ foo: 'bar', fizz: 'buzz' }, obj);console.log(obj);}`

Comment: @pilchard **EDIT**: I had a typo in my test for implementing this. Your solution works as I'd like. Thanks

Comment: It merges the properties that were passed in parameter object into the default object overwriting duplicate properties, all others stay as they are in the default `Object.assign({ foo: 'bar', fizz: 'buzz' }, { foo: 40, baz: 'rab' })`  --> `{ foo: 40, fizz: 'buzz', baz: 'rab' }` (equivalent to the spread operator answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try spread operator:

```js
function x(obj1 = {}) {
  let defaultObj =  {foo: 'bar', fizz: 'buzz',...obj1};  
  console.log(defaultObj);
}

x({foo: 10});
```

How this works is : `let x = {a: 1, b: 1, a:2}` will lead to `x = { a: 2 , b : 1}`, meaning properties defined later will overwrite properties(with same key) before them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object destructuring` in function parameter.

```js
function test({foo = 'bar', fizz = 'buzz'}) {
  console.log({foo, fizz});
}

test({foo: 40});
test({foo: 50, fizz: "abcde"});
```

[Check the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)